# Calling function inside function called by setTimeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to call the function `scroll_page` inside a function `call_scroll_page` that is called by `setTimeout`. And I get error `file.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: scroll_page is not a function`.

```
function scroll_page() {
    return false;
}
function call_scroll_page() {
    var scroll_page = scroll_page();
    if(!scroll_page) {
        $test = true;
    }
}
setTimeout(call_scroll_page, 1000);
```

Comment: var scroll_page = scroll_page(); <---- there. You can not use the same variable.... what do you think happens?

Comment: Thank you all, working ok now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> var scroll_page
> ```

You defined a new variable called `scroll_page` inside the `call_scroll_page` function which has masked the global one.

Rename that variable.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you are declaring a var with same name as your function. So inside your function `call_scroll_page()` scroll_page refers to the local variable. Change your variable name and it will work as intended.

```js
function scroll_page() {
    return false;
}
function call_scroll_page() {
    var scroll_page_var = scroll_page();
    if(!scroll_page_var) {
        $test = true;
    }
}
setTimeout(call_scroll_page, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

This line is causing the error: `var scroll_page = scroll_page();`

**Do not redeclare** something with name of the `scroll_page` function.

It removes the link to the function, replaced by a variable, calling a function that is no longer "callable by its name".

Try:

```
function scroll_page() {
    return false;
}
function call_scroll_page() {
    var fn = scroll_page();
    if(!fn) {
        $test = true;
    }
}
setTimeout(call_scroll_page, 1000);
```